# excluding value from GTM purchase event if specific product ID

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have a wordpress/woocommerce website which uses the GTM4WP plugin to send the website data to the GTM datalayer. In GTM I have successfully setup a purchase event which sends all data to the GA4 interface. So far so good.

Now there are two items (ID 224112 and 159324) on my website for which I do NOT want to see the revenue in my GA4 account. (The fact that they trigger a purchase event is not so much the problem but the revenue value should be ZERO.)

I have been searching for hours and found out I can do a custom Javascript function which should do the trick. Except I'm not very skilled with Javascript...

This is the instruction I found:

```
//This field should be a JavaScript function that returns a value using the 'return' statement. 
//If the function does not explicitly return a value, it will return undefined and your container may not behave as expected. 
//Below is an example of this field:
  function() {
    var now = new Date();
    return now.getTime();
  }
```

The value of both of these items can be different, I also run a multicurrency website, so the only thing we can go by is the ID.

When I do a test-purchase through the GTM preview mode I can see the following values in the data layer of the purchase event (I XXXed out a few things which are not needed here):

```
{
  event: "purchase",
  gtm: {uniqueEventId: 11, start: 1654376017109},
  visitorLoginState: "logged-in",
  visitorType: "XXX",
  pagePostType: "page",
  pagePostType2: "single-page",
  browserName: "Chrome",
  browserVersion: "102.0.5005.61",
  browserEngineName: "Blink",
  browserEngineVersion: "",
  deviceType: "desktop",
  deviceManufacturer: "Apple",
  deviceModel: "Macintosh",
  cartContent: {
    totals: {
      applied_coupons: [],
      discount_total: 0,
      subtotal: 0,
      total: 0
    },
    items: []
  },
  orderData: {
    attributes: {
      date: "2022-06-04T22:53:18+00:00",
      order_number: "226813",
      order_key: "wc_order_Z6HrzhCqQ3pTS",
      payment_method: "pensopay",
      payment_method_title: "Credit/Debit card",
      shipping_method: "3-5 days",
      status: "processing",
      coupons: ""
    },
    totals: {
      currency: "DKK",
      discount_total: "0",
      discount_tax: "0",
      shipping_total: "40",
      shipping_tax: "0",
      cart_tax: "0",
      total: "90.00",
      total_tax: "0",
      total_discount: "0",
      subtotal: "50",
      tax_totals: []
    },
    customer: {
      id: 3,
      billing: {
        first_name: "XXX",
        last_name: "XXX",
        company: "",
        address_1: "XXX",
        address_2: "",
        city: "XXX",
        state: "",
        postcode: "XXX",
        country: "DK",
        email: "XXX",
        emailhash: "dafb4416fe8aa737d5b09733b4d3310f6ca31276bebe6dd24" +
                   "bcbe1651fe4abde",
        phone: "XXX"
      },
      shipping: {
        first_name: "XXX",
        last_name: "XXX",
        company: "",
        address_1: "XXX",
        address_2: "",
        city: "XXX",
        state: "",
        postcode: "XXX",
        country: "DK"
      }
    },
    items: [
      {
        id: 224112,
        name: "Materials",
        sku: 224112,
        category: "XXX",
        price: 50,
        stocklevel: null,
        brand: "XXX",
        quantity: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  new_customer: false,
  ecommerce: {
    currencyCode: "DKK",
    purchase: {
      actionField: {
        id: "226813",
        affiliation: "",
        revenue: 90,
        tax: 0,
        shipping: 40,
        coupon: ""
      },
      products: [
        {
          id: 224112,
          name: "Materials",
          sku: 224112,
          category: "XXX",
          price: 50,
          stocklevel: null,
          brand: "XXX",
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    currency: "DKK",
    items: [
      {
        item_id: 224112,
        item_name: "Materials",
        item_brand: "XXX",
        price: 50,
        item_category: "XXX",
        quantity: 1,
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        id: "224112"
      }
    ],
    transaction_id: "226813",
    affiliation: "",
    value: 90,
    tax: 0,
    shipping: 40,
    coupon: ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be best to first not allow things that you don't want to have in DL. Since you just use plugins, then I would suggest to either make a change in the plugin logic to ignore specified products, or change the data. Just set the price for those products to the appropriate values.

Another approach to it would be through GA reporting. Just exclude the product ids you're not interested in from the reports.

I suggest these approaches because this is not a GTM issue really. Fixing this through GTM would be a hack and we try to avoid hacks in production.

Now that we went through that, yes, there are a few ways to fix it through GTM. An obvious one would be just to add a CJS blocker to your EEC trigger that would check if these products are in the ecommerce object and block the thing from firing if they're there. But this means blocking it for any other products that may be tracked in the same call.

You can also rebuild the whole ecommerce object with a CJS variable, the detailed explanation can be found here: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/enhanced-ecommerce-with-a-custom-javascript-variable/ in case you're using Universal Analytics.

There's a similar solution for GA4. A simpler one. In GA4, you override your DL EEC push by just setting an event parameter for your EEC tag that sets the `items` property. You would use a CJS as a value. In your CJS you should return a proper array of items by taking what's in the DL and sanitizing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see that fixing this with GTM would be a hack and not the best way. So I contacted the plugin developer to see if there is a way to exclude this data (or overwrite the value) from arriving into the datalayer.

Meanwhile I tried to see how to exclude this from the GA report. Do you have any article explaining how to do this? I could not find it on simple search...

Comment: Well I would try two things: using a filter, listing only the ids you want if you have just a few products, or a custom report, excluding unneeded products in filters.